# Preloading options for select with reactJS in Rails

Tags: reactjs, react-rails

I'm trying to do a select by dynamically loading options using React.

my form component:

```
...
React.DOM.select
  className: 'form-control'
  name: 'user'
  React.createElement UserOptions
```

user options component:

```
@UserOptions = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    connections: []

  componentDidMount: ->
    @getUsers()

  render: ->
    for connection in @state.connections  
      React.DOM.option
        value: connection.id
        label: connection.name

  getUsers: ->
    $.ajax 
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/connections'
      dataType: 'json'
      success: (connections) =>
        @setState(connections: connections)
```

When I try the page, javascript breaks (not loading anything) with an error

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Constructor.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

When trying to do the loading in `componentWillMount` callback, I get the same error +

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null`

I'm using `react-rails` gem.

weird thing is that when I debug inside success calllback, call the setState manually and then check the `connections` they are updated, but I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null` anyways

Any help will be appreciated. I'm new to React so maybe it's something trivial.